Getting a Failed to compile error in Next.js code
I am a beginner in Next.js and now I am getting this error while running 'npm run dev' command.
please help me to fix this error.
Here is the log of terminal
` *  History restored 

Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader and has disabled PSReadLine for compatibility purposes. If you want to re-enable it, run 'Import-Module PSReadLine'.

PS D:\xampp\htdocs\figma_clone> npm run dev

> figma_clone@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.4
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Environments: .env.local

 ✓ Ready in 3.6s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ⨯ ./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
./node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js
./node_modules/canvas/index.js
./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js
./node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js
./lib/canvas.ts
./app/page.tsx
 ⨯ ./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
./node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js
./node_modules/canvas/index.js
./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js
./node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js
./lib/canvas.ts
./app/page.tsx
 ⨯ ./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
./node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js
./node_modules/canvas/index.js
./node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js
./node_modules/f

I am persistently getting this error and now this is in my fresh default code too, I have reinstalled the node.js from my computer and also changed the version with NVM but still nothing happened. Still I am getting the same error.
please help guys I am stuck at this and not able to learn further in Next.js enter image description here
